# What's the equivalent to Unwrap for a ConfiguredTaskAwaitable?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I'm creating a (well adapting an existing) helper class to allow me to run `async` methods synchronously.  So far I've got the task factory and a static method that lets me run `async` methods synchronously as long as I don't configure them with `.ConfigureAwait`, because `.ConfigureAwait` turns the return value of the method from a `System.Threading.Tasks.Task<T>` to a `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable<T>`.  The code looks like this:

```
public static class AsyncUtils {
    private static readonly TaskFactory _taskFactory =
        new TaskFactory(
            CancellationToken.None,
            TaskCreationOptions.None,
            TaskContinuationOptions.None,
            TaskScheduler.Default
        );

    public static TResult RunSync<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>> func) {
        return _taskFactory
            .StartNew<Task<TResult>>(func)
            .Unwrap<TResult>()
            .GetAwaiter()
            .GetResult();
    }
}
```

If I try to add a method to deal with `ConfiguredTaskAwaitable<T>`, it might look like this:

```
    public static TResult RunSync<TResult>(Func<ConfiguredTaskAwaitable<TResult>> func) {
        return _taskFactory
            .StartNew<ConfiguredTaskAwaitable<TResult>>(func)
            .Unwrap<TResult>() // Doesn't exist!
            .GetAwaiter()
            .GetResult();
    }
```

The trouble is, as can be seen from the comment, `StartNew<ConfiguredTaskAwaitable>` returns a `Task<ConfiguredTaskAwaitable<TResult>>` instead of a `Task<Task<TResult>>` meaning that the `Unwrap` method doesn't exist for it.  Is there an equivalent?  How can I create an equivalent method for `ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`?

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Comment: @Jez: I second Yuval's question: why? I can also say from experience that **it is not possible** to create a generic sync-over-async wrapper that works correctly in all scenarios.

Comment: It's an application that needs to go off and call a web service on startup (the web service call is async), and can only continue once it gets the response.  It might not be an ideally-coded app but I have to maintain it. :-)

Comment: @Jez there are other ways to get around that problem. If you're making async calls from a constructor, don't. Utilize the initializer pattern. E.g, if you're using a WinForms application, use the FormLoaded event and make the async call there.

Comment: How about you answer my actual question instead of telling me to do things differently?

Comment: Because you are asking a "[old shoe or glass bottle?](http://weblogs.asp.net/alex_papadimoulis/408925)" question, we are just trying to helpfully tell you that you should be using a hammer.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I think that's an exaggeration.  There are definitely times when one wants to call async code from a sync method.

Comment: Yes, but your example of calling a web service is not one of them. Use a sync method to call it (it may require switching from `HttpClient` to `WebClient`) or use one of the patterns Yuval talked about.

Comment: FFS why?  How hard can it be to wrap an async method in a single-user application and wait until the call is complete?  By the way I'm using an OWIN WebApp which wraps an `HttpClient` in the background so I don't really have the option of choosing that.  I'm saying there's a hole in my boat and you guys are basically saying "start building an aeroplane, that's the proper way to cross the ocean".  I know this is sub-optimal but bullshit is it "impossible" to call async code from sync code in an acceptable way.

Comment: @Jez the essential thing to take away here is there is no good way to do it. Sometimes that's OK, and if it's OK with you, then you need to make sure you know the risks (like, deadlock) and can navigate around them smoothly. But your initial code indicates you may not have that level of knowledge yet, so these guys were trying to steer you toward a more overall robust architecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ConfigureAwait()` only controls how the context is resumed after an `await`. If you're getting the result synchronously, it will have no effect because there is no "resume".

Additionally, one would typically run async methods synchronously by just doing this:

```
TResult RunSync<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>> func) {
    return func().Result;
}
```

Or this, if you want to force it to run on the thread pool:

```
TResult RunSync<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>> func) {
    return Task.Run(func).Result;
}
```

Comment: Well for some reason Microsoft did it a different way. :-)  Something to do with unwrapping exceptions that happen in the async method?

Comment: The difference is semantical. `GetAwaiter.GetResult` will yield the internal unwrapped exception while `Task.Result` will yield an `AggregateException`. Both are highly likely to cause deadlocks (excluding when `ConfiguredTaskAwaitable` is set to false)

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov So actually I could do with a `RunSync` method that takes a `ConfiguredTaskAwaitable` so I can set it to false?